# PHP echo statement escaping from containing DIV element

Tags: php, html, dom, echo

Background: I'm editing a custom admin page for WordPress 3.4.2 which is part of a plugin I'm making.

I have a little snippet of PHP code in my HTML that checks for the existence of a variable and prints it if it has a value:

```
<div id='ajax-response'>
    <?php
    if(isset($_infos) && !empty($_infos)){
        echo $_infos;
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

However, when the page runs in a way that means the variable has a value, the output is not actually inside that #ajax-response `<div>` but directly above it like this:

```
<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p>Download display details updated.</p></div>
<div id='ajax-response'></div>
```

The whole point of the #ajax-response `<div>` is to contain all feedback provided, both from the page itself and any AJAX calls, so they are all displayed together and with the same styling - and can all be removed from the page easily - so this is quite annoying.

The strangest bit is that when I view source it is inside the #ajax-response `<div>` like it should be, but in Chrome's inspector and when referenced by Javascript it is treated as though its outside of the `<div>`.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Could you please show how it looks in View Source?

Comment: Does your other HTML code validate? Wondering if there is a `<div>` somewhere that's not been opened/closed properly which is causing you the nesting troubles...

Comment: Why do you use single `'` in `<div id='ajax-response'></div>` and double `"` in `<div id="message" class="updated fade">`?

Comment: There is no way PHP would rearrange your output in the way you state. You must have javascript doing this on the client-side, or you've got a mangled HTML page and the browser is trying to correct the mangling.

Comment: Browsers try to fix invalid HTML, and often get it wrong.  Have you tried [an html validator](http://validator.w3.org/)?

Comment: @Kolink here's a screenshot showing both the inspector and source views in Chrome (22.0.1229.92 m) - http://i.imgur.com/zscVZ.png

Comment: @SetSailMedia and @h0tw1r3 I just did a direct input validation using the W3C validator and only get errors for having empty `action` attributes.
@Bondye I'm not entirely sure, its probably a result of copy-and-pasting between pages.

Comment: Not likely to help your cause but you should definitely keep your use of double and single quotes consistent. I would opt for double quotes as I don't recall seeing single quotes too often.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but please check php file which gives output to your javascript file. or try alert(Responce from php file) in js file before replacing the content of ajax-responce div.

Answer (score 0):

I know this topic is dead, but I was having the exact same issue with several pieces of code that I had written. It was ECHO causing the problem. When I swapped my function to RETURN rather than ECHO, it fixed it immediately.